# Cesium | Any Alternatives to 3dtilesets to visualize point cloud data?

Tags: visualisation, cesium, point-cloud

I'm in the early stages of developing a web-based visualization for multiple GIS data sources (imagery, vector data sets, terrain, point cloud...etc).  I am using the Cesium javascript library for this visualization.  And so far, so good...

When it comes to visualizing point cloud data, Cesium has off-the-shelf rendering capability for 3dtilesets generated for a point cloud.  I am hoping to possible sidestep this requirement.  I'm hoping I could just stream some point cloud data to the browser, and render.  I started messing around with PointPrimitive & PointPrimitiveCollection - but initial results don't seem very promising.

Can anyone point me to some examples of rendering point cloud data in Cesium not using 3dtilesets?  I can say upfront I don't intend to visualize a billion points...  I don't have any hard & cold numbers - but something like 1-2 million points would be a good start.